# What PDF meta data does dompdf support?

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf

When using dompdf what PDF meta data can be set in the document information dictionary?

Originally asked [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32076596/264628):

> Are you able to parse more META info to be added to PDF information during PDF generation?
>
> /Creator (DOMPDF)
>   /CreationDate (D:20150818031116-05'00')
>   /ModDate (D:20150818031116-05'00')
>
> Can you specify Author, Copyright, etc..?
>
> I cannot find ANY reference to this. Only just saw your: Creator, Creation Date and Modification Date!

Answer (score 15):

In the current stable release (0.6.1) the HTML `<title>` element and some `<meta>` elements (author, keywords, description) are used to set the relevant PDF meta data.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ehhhhhhh</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Arthur Herbert Fonzarelli">
  <meta name="keywords" content="fonzie, cool, ehhhhhhh">
</head>
<body>
  <p>Ehhhhhhh</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition, you can add other info to the PDF using the `$dompdf->add_info()` method. The full list of supported metadata info that you can set is: Title, Author, Subject, Keywords, Creator, Producer, CreationDate, ModDate, Trapped.

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->add_info('Subject', 'Cool');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dompdf->add_info('Title', 'Your meta Title');
                $dompdf->add_info('Author', 'Your meta Author');
                $dompdf->add_info('Subject', 'Your meta Subject');
                $dompdf->add_info('Keywords', 'Your meta Keywords');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.